# My content is more to the right than it is to the left?

Tags: html, css

I've never had this issue before in my life, nor did I noticed it until I tested it on my iPhone.

Appearantly both of my divs are more to the right than they are to the left.

[image]

Here's my codes for the content area, as well as the tables if needed.

Divs for the content area

```css
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
    clear: both;
    display: none;
}
#index {
    display: block;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Divs/classes for the Tables

```css
.table-default, .table-blue, .table-red {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.table-default, .table-blue, .table-red i {
    color: 000;
}
.table-default  th {
    background: #eeeeee;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #000;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #B2B2B2;
}
.table-default  td {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-    right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #B2B2B2;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the HTML& CSS together...perhaps in a JSfiddle Demo?

Comment: Both links look fine to me. Equal space on either side.

Comment: @Lee they're not equal

Comment: Let me get a free webhosting so you can see real quick.

Comment: @CameronSwyft Or create a demo in JSfiddle.net it's what most of us do.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familliar with JSfiddle. :(

Comment: http://ctstudios.net46.net/

Comment: I thougth the problem wat that the right div is taking more space, since it has to host the "non-breaking" image, but I just was to start gettint some doubts about it, that's why I just deleted it.

Comment: The ad is just a stock image, nothing there.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle

Comment: If you add `overflow: hidden` to `.content` you will see what the problem is. The image is wider than it's container. The container itself is centred however the image is leaking over the edge.

Comment: The problem is that the `#right` has `width: 25%`, but for most screens that isn't wide enough for its content, which overflows to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is why the `.content` is not in the center: then the answer is, it is. What you're seeing is the overflow. Which is evident if you apply `overflow:hidden`

Also note that, at the moment the `.content` has 0 height so in fact everything is overflowing. Eliminating the overflow of `.content` will fix the issue.

This is how it looks like once you apply a proper height and hide the overflow:

[image: debug result]

You can adjust the width of `#left` (`70%`) and `#right` (`30%`) to remove the overflow which results in

> [image: final result]

Comment: Ah alright, thanks! One more question though if you don't mind.. I have this as my Table Headers now

<table class="table-default" width="100%" style="margin: 25px;">

But, the margin only effects the top and bottom, it doesn't space between here and the Advertisement table, is there a reason?

Comment: @CameronSwyft If you just want spacing in between then instead of `margin` try giving `padding`... By the way, if you apply either `margin` or `padding` it changes the effective size of the element, so you'll have to either re-calculate the width and height accordingly or apply `box-sizing:border-box` to keep things in position

Comment: I thought I had to use margin's for it, thanks so much! I'm still a newbie to CSS in general so :)